# Facebook page fans didn't get notification for image upload using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications, image-uploading, facebook-page, feed

I use this code for uploading an image to the album on my own Facebook page.

```
$facebook = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  "app_id" => {app-id},
  "app_secret" => {app-secret},
  "default_graph_version" => "v2.10",
  "default_access_token" => {access-token}                                     
]);

$data["caption"] = {caption};
$data["url"] = {url};
$facebook->post("/{album-id}/photos", $data);
```

The image is properly uploaded and viewed on News Feed (my page and fan users' as well) but fans didn't get notification about it.

When I am using the Graph API Explorer the behaviour is the same.

The access token has this scopes: manage_pages, pages_show_list, publish_pages, public_profile.

I found out yet when I use a parameter "no_story = true", fans get notification now. But the image isn't viewed on News Feed of course.

What am I doing wrong? Is it generally possible to view an image on News Feed together with notification (using Graph API)? When I upload an image directly through Facebook page (manually), everything is OK.

Comment: Works as designed, I guess. Likely implemented this way to protect users from being flooded with such notifications.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But there is a question why fans get notification in case a parameter "no_story = true". Now I am wondering that I would upload an image with parameter "no_story = true" and after that post a message to the page News Feed. But how to insert an image? Preferably the image with the same ID like in the first post (without its duplication).